# How to map compose key to insert via setxkbmap?

Tags: keyboard-layout, unicode, xkb, compose-key, setxkbmap

I'm using US (non-international) layout. One way of typing üäöß is setting a compose key via:
`setxkbmap -layout us -option compose:ralt`
Unfortunately, this removes the normal "alt" functionality from right alt.

1- I figured `insert` key is useless in modern editors. How to map the compose key to it? The list of available options does only include few keys:
`grep "compose:" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`

```
  compose:lwin         Left Win
  compose:lwin-altgr   3rd level of Left Win
  compose:rwin         Right Win
  compose:rwin-altgr   3rd level of Right Win
  compose:menu         Menu
  compose:menu-altgr   3rd level of Menu
  compose:lctrl        Left Ctrl
  compose:lctrl-altgr  3rd level of Left Ctrl
  compose:rctrl        Right Ctrl
  compose:rctrl-altgr  3rd level of Right Ctrl
  compose:caps         Caps Lock
  compose:caps-altgr   3rd level of Caps Lock
  compose:102          &lt;Less/Greater&gt;
  compose:102-altgr    3rd level of &lt;Less/Greater&gt;
  compose:paus         Pause
  compose:prsc         PrtSc
  compose:sclk         Scroll Lock
```

2- Is there a way to retain the "alt" functionality when it is mapped to compose?

3- Is there a way to make right_alt, as AltGr without changing the keyboard layout to international?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use `setxkbmap` for that? I mean you can do `setxkbmap us` and then, change individual keys with `xmodmap`.

Comment: @ewen-goisot I set a couple of options with `setxkbmap` (like mapping caps to escape), I think `xmodmap` configs would get resetted when I invoke `setxkbmap`? Should I just do my `xmodmap`s after `setxkbmap` in my init rc?

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator Yes, you should put `xmodmap`s after `setxkbmap`. Or there is at least one other way : manually edit your `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbol/us` and simply run `setxkbmap us`. I will try to give you a more detailed answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using `xmodmap` (answers `1` and `3`)

The `setxkbmap us -option` is for predefined options with very specific behaviors. I don't think you can find what you want here until you want to do something similar to many people.
What you can do instead using `xmodmap` :

```
    setxkbmap us
    xmodmap -e "keycode 118 = Multi_key"
    xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
```

2nd line is for `Compose` (also named `Multi_key`) on `Insert` key (answer `1`),
3rd line is for `AltGr` (also named `ISO_Level3_Shift` … be aware there is also a `ISO_Level5_Shift` but very few person use it), on the right `Alt` key (answer `3`).

If you only want `3`, then, try with `setxkbmap us -option lv3:ralt_switch`.

### Keep `alt` while remaped (answer `2`)

Your `grep` command gave you some options, but not all of them.
You can search in `man 7 xkeyboard-config` instead,
you will see at least one more that does mostly but not exactly what you want :

```
    lv3:ralt_switch_multikey   Right Alt; Shift+Right Alt as Compose
```

Actually, I'm not sure I perfectly understood your question, I assumed it's something like :
`press Compose, press Foo, release Foo, release Compose` is supposed to do `Alt-Foo`,
while `press Compose, release Compose` is supposed to do `Multi_key` (compose),
but what do you want it to do if you do, let's say
`press Compose, press Foo, release Compose, release Foo` ?
Or what should it do if you press 3 keys or more ?

If you want something like that… it's a much more advanced feature.
It's possible to truly do this with some mechanical keyboards like [Ergodox](https://ergodox-ez.com/), or others supporting [QMK](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/) (look at `Dual-function key`), but not sure there is a way with `setxkbmap`.

Comment: Thanks for this through answer!  
Does `setxkbmap -option lv3:ralt_switch_multikey` keep "alt" functionality of right alt? It does register shift+ralt as compose key, but removes the regular alt functionality from it. For example, I can no longer ctrl+alt+delete with right alt or go-forward in firefox (alt+ right_arrow)

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator With this option, if I press the right `Alt` key with anything except `Shift`, it does an `AltGR` (maybe not a regular `Alt`). `setxkbmap` has limited number of that kind of features, and I didn't found the equivalent without `AltGR`. Look at it in the manual : it says `Key to choose the 3rd level` and 3rd level is related to `AltGR`.